# How to capture/get camera White Balance value using camera2 API or CameraX library while camera is open and before image capturing

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to get the white balancing value at runtime while the user opens the camera. I want to show user some message if the current white balance value is not in some specified range.

Comment: Did you achieve it?

Comment: Not able to find any solution yet

Comment: I've worked on it and its working fine, let me share my it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback callback and implement its function like

```
private val captureCallbackListener: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback =
    object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureStarted(..){}
        override fun onCaptureProgressed(..){}
        override fun onCaptureCompleted(
            session: CameraCaptureSession,
            request: CaptureRequest,
            result: TotalCaptureResult
        ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureCompleted White Balance: ${result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE)} and ${result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS)} and ${result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM)}")

          }

}
```

These logs above will provide you all info related to White Balance.
Pass this callback while creating camera preview in cameraCaptureSessions!!.setRepeatingRequest as

```
 cameraCaptureSessions!!.setRepeatingRequest(
        captureRequestBuilder!!.build(),
        captureCallbackListener,
        mBackgroundHandler
    )
```